# Iterating through the options of a drop down

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium in Ruby ( a language that I am currently learning) and I have a drop down menu that I want to iterate though, select each option, do some stuff, and then move onto the next option.

I have looked at several answers that are somewhat similar. Only one Stack Overflow question had to similar idea in mind as mine but it's in Python and I just don't know the syntax for Ruby.

I have read through the documentation for Ruby and haven't found anything that does anything similar to the Python way.

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
   select first option
        click a button
        navigate to a different page
        download a csv
        return back to the previous page

   select second option
        do the same thing
etc...until all the options are done
```

Is this possible? I can figure out returning to the previous page and clicking the csv option but I would like some help on the syntax part.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby bindings for `selenium-webdriver` have a [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/Select.html) class for manipulating select lists.

Here's a contrived example that locates a select_list element, passed the element to a Select object, and prints the text of each option in the list.  YMMV...

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html"

element = driver.find_element(id: 'select-demo')

select_list = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(element)
select_list.options.each { |option| puts option.text}

#=> Please select
#=> Sunday
#=> Monday
#=> Tues
...
```

Comment: In order to use the other options of the support class, would I write Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.first_selected_option()?

Comment: You can select individual options in the dropdown via `select_by`.

Comment: @Herbert H. Please accept this answer if it answers your question. Give the credit to the people those who are answering your questions.